# mocked ReactiveElasticsearchOperations search method retruns null

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mockito, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-boot-test

I have mocked ReactiveElasticsearchOperations using @MockeBean for search method but it retruns null.

the test code is :

```
when(reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(
            query, NutchDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("test")))
        .thenReturn(Flux.just(TestObjectFactory.getDocumentSearchHit(TestObjectFactory.getNutchDocument())));
```

the source code is :

```
Flux<SearchHit<T>> searchHits =
        reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(query, clazz, IndexCoordinates.of(INDEX_NAME));
```

Comment: How did you setup your test class?

Comment: As the mock is returning `null` this might indicate that your stubbing setup does not equal the actual arguments that were passed to your mock during test execution. Did you already debug it and made sure they are what you expect? As a quick _hack_ you can temporarily use `ArgumentMatchers.any()` for all arguments and check if it works

Comment: @rieckpil I have followed your idea but did not work.

Comment: can you add the code that followed my idea and did not work?